# How to override the network DHCP Server settings to be specific to my own .conf file?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, dhclient, pac, wpad.dat

Basically, I have want to test out WPAD(Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol ) , PAC. But I would like to do it without touching the Network DHCP server. So, can you suggest a way in which I can achieve that.

Will changing the local `/etc/dhclient.conf` file be enough ?

Thanks

Comment: What part do you want to test? The PAC file? DHCP discovery? DNS discovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override specific options in the DHCP client configuration `/etc/dhclient.conf`:

```
option wpad-url code 252 = text;
interface "eth0" {
    supersede wpad-url "http://wpad.example.com/proxy.pac";
}
```